# How to create options for Python markdown custom extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-markdown

I'm trying to add an option to my custom markdown extension in python3. Unfortuantely I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "pymodules/docmarkdown.py", line 232, in get_leaflang_markdown
    MyFencedCodeExtension(deflang = "leaf"),
  File "pymodules/docmarkdown.py", line 61, in __init__
    super(MyFencedCodeExtension,self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deflang'
```

The constructor code of the extension is below. It follows the pattern provided by the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html#configsettings).

```
class MyFencedCodeExtension(markdown.extensions.Extension):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.config = { 'deflang' : [ None, "language if not specified" ] }

        super(MyFencedCodeExtension,self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I'm referencing the extension when constructing the Markdown instance:

```
return markdown.Markdown(
    safe_mode = 'escape',
    extensions = [
        'meta',
        'toc',
        MyFencedCodeExtension(deflang = "leaf"),
        CenterExtension({}),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is happening on your `super()` call.

The superclass of `MyFencedCodeExtension` is `markdown.extensions.Extension`.

According to the error message, the superclass constructor is not expecting the keyword argument `deflang`.

Look at the signature of `markdown.extensions.Extension.__init__` to work out what it is expecting.

Comment: Yes, I understand specifically what the error means. My question is how to do this correctly for an extension.  This setup comes directly from the docs -- I was assuming it was doing something tricky with `config`, but it may indeed just be a mistake in the docs.

Comment: That is why I suggested you go and look at the constructor signature. If you follow a recipe exactly and you get that sort of exception thrown, then the problem is probably with the recipe. My guess is spelling or capitalization.